# emacs Jedi disable #

Tags: python, emacs, autocomplete, emacs24, emacs-jedi

I have a working version of JEDI with Emacs 24.3 on osx.  The autocomplete feature is wonderful, except for when I want to comment things out!  I frequently comment/uncomment portions of my code and was hoping there was a way to prevent JEDI's auto completion from coming up when I type #.  Any advice or thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

edit:  When I go to comment multiple lines I enter in # typically followed by DownArrow and LeftArrow, but what usually happens with JEDI enabled is this dialog pops up preventing me from moving to the following line until I make a selection:
[image: dialog that pops up]

Comment: I do not get auto-completion in comments, what is the value of the variable `ac-disable-faces`? Just do `C-h v`ac-disable-faces`RET` emacs will pop up a help buffer with the variable's value.

Comment: I apologize for the previous comment, I had JEDI disabled so I wan't getting a value returned.  Here is the result:

ac-disable-faces is a variable defined in `auto-complete.el'.
Its value is (font-lock-comment-face font-lock-string-face font-lock-doc-face)


Documentation:
Non-nil means disable automatic completion on specified faces.

You can customize this variable.

[back]

Comment: I just updated jedi and I observe the behavior you have reported. This seems to be a bug introduced due to some recent changes. This should reported to the emacs-jedi developers

Comment: Not exactly a solution but a workaround can be to set `ac-delay` to a larger value, default value is 0.1 that is completion is started after 0.1 seconds. Set it to a larger value (say 0.7) like so `(setq ac-delay 0.7)` this might help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [company-jedi](https://github.com/proofit404/company-jedi) for your python completion. This package doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get around this issue would be to select the lines (region) you would like to comment out and hit <kbd>M-;</kbd>. This runs the command `comment-dwim` which comments out the selected region (or uncomments it, if it is currently commented out).

When used in conjunction with e.g. [`mark-lines`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/mark-lines.el) which allows you to select the current line with a single key stroke, this makes for a really fast way of (un)commenting portions of your code, even if they span just one or two lines.

Answer (score 0):

emacs-jedi dev here.  If emacs-jedi works as you describe, then that's a bug.

But I cannot say what is wrong from the limited information I have.  So, just general directions:

1. First, *always* try to reproduce the misbehavior in a clean Emacs setting, described here http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/latest/#quick-try

   This helps you to find out if your setting is wrong or if it is actually a bug in emacs-jedi.
2. Give the output of `M-x jedi:show-version-info`. http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/latest/#jedi:show-version-info

   This helps people diagnosing the problem.
3. This is a guess from your screenshot but it seems that you have old version of popup.el.  So maybe auto-complete.el could be old one if you install them at the same time.  If you don't see the problem in the clean Emacs (step 1. I mentioned above) which installs newest libraries, then updating them could solve the problem.

**Update**

So, I found a way to reproduce the behavior which is close to what you mentioned: https://github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi/issues/147

But as I wrote in the issue, I think it is a rare case.  If you find a case which could happen very frequently, then let me know.